# How is array passed to a function?

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays, memory-address

Consider the following:

```
String[] array = {1,2,3,4};

myFunction(array);

public void myFunction(String[] array){
//some task here
}
```

I had to answer this question today.

**How are arrays passed to a function? Means what is the underlying technique?**

When I failed to answer, I was told the following.

The address of first element is passed and other consecutive elements are obtained from the first element's address by adding some **x bytes**.

**Does this happen in every programming language or in just c and c++?**

Thank you!

Comment: "Does this happen in every programming language?" Of course not. Not all languages have functions and arrays. And neither C nor C++ allows you to pass an array to a function; only a pointer to the first element or (in C++) a reference to an array.

Comment: Array allocates consective memory location so I think its possible in languages other than C/C++.

Comment: so that is the way how arrays are dealt in certain programming languages?

Comment: only c and c++ are concerned with such address passing. The ugly usage of pointers are only in C and C++ (Java, C# don't need you to do this, they just need the array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in Java for example arrays are objects. They are passed like any other object is passed to a method: the method would take a reference to the array object as a whole, and not a reference to the first element.

Taken from [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2):

> All class and array types inherit (§8.4.8) the methods of class Object

Java has no concept of "pointers", in the same sense as C or C++ (addresses in memory), i.e. an object reference does not really point to the memory location where the object is stored.

Comment: Java definitely has pointers; it just calls them references.  Whether the actual pointer on the stack points directly to the object or not is irrelevant; it's an implementation detail (and there's no requirement that the physical data in a C++ pointer designate a physical address in memory either).

Comment: Of course, the concept of a pointer in C++ is quite different than the one in Java. In Java, you could treat every reference to an object as a "pointer".

Answer (score 3):

In theory, every language is different.  However:

- In C, a function cannot take an array as an argument.  When
  you declare an array parameter, the type is automatically
  converted into a pointer, so there is no different between 
  `void f( int a[5] )` and `void f( int* )`.  (This is often
  summarized by saying that arrays are not first class objects.)
  For reasons of C compatibility, C++ follows the same rules, but
  in C++, you wouldn't normally pass an array as a parameter
  anyway, and if you did, you would pass it by reference, where
  this conversion to pointer doesn't occur. (I.e.
  `void f( int (&a)[5] )` is *not* the same as `void f( int* &a )`.)
- In Java, and a number of other recent languages, everything
  (or almost), including arrays are objects, and parameters,
  variables, etc. are pointers to those objects.  So in Java, you
  pass a pointer to the array, but the full array object, with
  all of the information about its size, etc.  Sort of like
  passing an `std::vector<int>*` in C++.
- In a lot of languages (mostly older?), like Pascal and
  languages of the Modula family, and array is an object type just
  like any other.  If you don't take any particular actions, an
  array will be passed by value, with a complete copy of the
  array.
- And in the earliest languages, like Fortran or Algol, each
  language often had its own very particular ways of passing
  arrays, although in general, they followed the same rules as other
  types.  (Some early languages like Cobol or Basic, didn't even
  support passing arguments to functions, at least in their
  earliest variants.)

Amongst the languages you're likely to see today, I think that
the Java model predominates.  C remains an outlier, and C++
gives you the choice: you can pass an `std::vector` by value or
by reference (but reference is recommended for performance
reasons).